# Prove that $M;N;Q$ are colinear.

Tags: geometry

Consider a circle $O$ is circumcircle of $\Delta ABC$. $H$ is orthocenter of $\Delta ABC$. Let $P$ be the point on the circumcircle of $\Delta HBC$ $(P \ne B; C; H)$ and in $\Delta ABC$. The intersection of $PB$ and the circle $O$ is $M$; $PC$ and the circle $O$ is N. The intersection of $BM$ and $AC$ is $E$; $CN$ and $AB$ is $F$. The intersection of circumcircle of $\Delta AME$ and circumcircle of $\Delta ANF$ is $Q$. Prove that $M;N;Q$  are colinear.

---

I will prove $\angle AMQ$=$\angle AMN$ $M;N;Q$  are colinear.

We have:

$AMCN$ is cyclic quadrilateral $\rightarrow \angle AMN=\angle ACN$

$AMEQ$ is cyclic quadrilateral $\rightarrow \angle AMQ=\angle AEQ$

Or we need to prove $\angle ACN=\angle AEQ$

Or $QE//CN$. I tried Thales's theorem but failed, help me solve it. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$\angle BPC = \angle BHC = 180^\circ - \angle BAC,$$
$AFPE$ is circular, and so
$$\angle NFA + \angle AEM.$$
But $\angle NFA = \angle NQA$ and $\angle MEA = \angle MQA$, so
$$\angle NQA + \angle MQA = 180^\circ,$$
and we are done.

---

Note: The above solution is for $P$ on the arc ${BCH}$. It needs some modification when $P$ is on the other arc.